# Does JabRef add all references to the bibliograpy in LaTeX?

Tags: bibliographies, subdividing, jabref

Does cited articles/books in JabRef add all of the references to bibliography in LaTeX even though you did not cite them in the thesis?
Because I have one JabRef file and I want to add bibliography to end of the each chapter, but it adds all of the references to the each chapters.

Comment: Jabref is just a graphical interface to manage your database (the `.bib` file). Then when you call `bibtex` on a specific document, it looks for the cited references in the `.bib` file. To understand why all the references are included in your case, we would need a minimal working example. Are you using `\nocite{*}` anywhere?

Comment: i use \citep{...}

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It seems that you want chapterwise bibliographies.

This can be done with [`bibunits`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/bibunits) which works together with `natbib`.
Just put `\putbib` where you want the chapter bibliography and add the following to the preamble.

```
\let\stdthebibliography\thebibliography
\renewcommand{\thebibliography}{%
  \let\section\subsection
  \stdthebibliography}

\bibliographyunit[\section]
\bibliography*{\jobname}
\bibliographystyle*{plainnat}
```

This makes sure that you can use `\putbib` in the `\section`s; `\bibliography*{\jobname}` specifies the `.bib` source file while `\bibliographystyle*{plainnat}` specifies the bibliography style (`.bst` file)

```
\documentclass[american]{article}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{bibunits}

\let\stdthebibliography\thebibliography
\renewcommand{\thebibliography}{%
  \let\section\subsection
  \stdthebibliography}

\bibliographyunit[\section]
\bibliography*{\jobname}
\bibliographystyle*{plainnat}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{testart,
  author        = {Arnold Uthor and William Riter},
  title         = {A Very Interesting Article},
  journal       = {Journal of Articles},
  volume        = {7},
  number        = {3},
  pages         = {1-5},
  year          = {2010},
}
@book{testbookt,
  author        = {Arnold Uthor},
  title         = {Long Book},
  date          = {1990},
}
@book{testbook,
  author        = {Walter Ordsmith},
  editor        = {Eddie Ditor},
  title         = {The Work},
  subtitle      = {Subtitle},
  year          = {1983},
}
@online{testonline,
  author        = {Bernie Logger},
  title         = {A Very Opinionated Blog Post},
  url           = {http://example.com},
  year          = {2013},
}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}
  \section{First section}
    some text \citep{testart} more text more citations
    \putbib

  \section{Second section}
    some text \citep{testonline} more text more citations
    \putbib

\end{document}
```

[image]

---

You can also use [`biblatex`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/biblatex), `biblatex` has a `natbib` compatibility mode (see § 3.7.9, p.88, of the [documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/doc/biblatex.pdf)).
For more about multiple bibliographies, see §3.6.4 and 3.11.3 of the [`biblatex` documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/doc/biblatex.pdf).
Put this in your preamble

```
\usepackage[style=authoryear,backend=biber,natbib,refsection=section]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
```

but *do not load* `natbib` or other citation packages.
With `refsection=section` every `\section` is a refsection in its own right, so you can put `\printbibliography[heading=subbibliography]` where you want the bibliography for that particluar section to go.

```
\documentclass[american]{article}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=authoryear,backend=biber,natbib,refsection=section]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{testart,
  author        = {Arnold Uthor and William Riter},
  title         = {A Very Interesting Article},
  journal       = {Journal of Articles},
  volume        = {7},
  number        = {3},
  pages         = {1-5},
  year          = {2010},
}
@book{testbookt,
  author        = {Arnold Uthor},
  title         = {Long Book},
  date          = {1990},
}
@book{testbook,
  author        = {Walter Ordsmith},
  editor        = {Eddie Ditor},
  title         = {The Work},
  subtitle      = {Subtitle},
  year          = {1983},
}
@online{testonline,
  author        = {Bernie Logger},
  title         = {A Very Opinionated Blog Post},
  url           = {http://example.com},
  year          = {2013},
}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}
  \section{First section}
    some text \citep{testart} more text more citations
    \printbibliography[heading=subbibliography]

  \section{Second section}
    some text \citep{testonline} more text more citations
    \printbibliography[heading=subbibliography]
\end{document}
```

[image]